# javafx: How do I set the bounds of a Group so it shows a specific window of the many shapes inside, which may or may not exceed my intended bounds?

Tags: javafx

I have a JavaFX Group that contains a lot of ImageViews and a few overlays.  I want it to render a specific mathematical rectangle which usually does not match the bounding box of the combined children.  For a simpler concrete example I have created the following app:

```
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.*;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.stage.*;

public class GroupWindow
    extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
        throws Exception
    {
        Group gr = new Group();

        Shape circle1 = new Circle(-300, 0, 50);
        circle1.setFill(Color.GREEN);
        gr.getChildren().add(circle1);

        Shape circle2 = new Circle(0, 300, 50);
        circle2.setFill(Color.GREEN);
        gr.getChildren().add(circle2);

        Shape LLrect = new Rectangle(-200, 0, 200,200);
        LLrect.setFill(Color.BLUE);
        gr.getChildren().add(LLrect);

        VBox vbox = new VBox(gr);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(vbox));

        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

When I run the application I get a window that looks like
 [image: blue square and two green circles]

What I need is for it to look like

[image: blue square in lower left corner]

I could accomplish this if I knew the method call that would tell the Group to restrict its viewport to x in [-200..200] and y in [-200..200].

One comment suggests setting a clip.  Adding a `gr.setClip(new Rectangle(-200,-200, 400,400));` causes it to not draw the green circles, but the rendered window encompasses the same space as the first (undesirable) screenshot.  So the clip does not affect how the Group decides its rendering window.

What technique should I use to specify this intent to javafx's layout engine?

Comment: See if setting [a clip](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#clipProperty) works for you.